# Trigger to calculate Average date of closed opportunity if its closed won?

Tags: trigger, updaterecord, after

```apex
public class AverageDateOpportunityHandler {
   
public static void afterUpdateMethod(List<Opportunity> oppList) {
        

Integer totalDays = 0;

        for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
            if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' && opp.CloseDate != null) {
            Integer daysDifference = Integer.valueof(opp.CloseDate.daysBetween(opp.CreatedDate));
            totalDays += daysDifference;
            }
        }

        // Calculate average or perform other actions based on the totalDays.
        if (oppList.size() > 0) {
            Integer averageDays = totalDays / oppList.size();
            // Perform actions with the averageDays, e.g., logging or updating a field.
            System.debug('Average Closed Date for Closed Won Opportunities: ' + averageDays);
        }
    }
}
```

```apex
//This is the trigger
trigger AverageDateOpportunity on Opportunity (after update) {
    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate){
    AverageDateOpportunityHandler.afterupdatemethod(trigger.New);   
    }
}
```

I am getting the Error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void daysBetween(Datetime) from the type Date

Comment: opp.CreatedDate is not a Date. It's a DateTime. Salesforce is going to feel forever sorry to have named these fields "Date".

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce.  Be sure to read [help] and [ask].  If you check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_daysBetween), you'll see that `daysBetween()` expects a Date data type, but `CreatedDate` is a DateTime data type.  You will have to change it using the `date()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Felix Van Howe says, `CreatedDate` is a `Datetime` field, so, you'll need to extract the date portion from the Datetime.

(and I rewrote this to be crisper)

```
public static void afterUpdateMethod(List<Opportunity> opportunities) {        
    Integer totalDays = 0;
    for (Opportunity opp: opportunities) {
      if (!opp.isClosed) {continue;}
      if (!opp.IsWon) {continue;}
      totalDays += opp.CloseDate.daysBetween(opp.CreatedDate.date());
    }

    Integer averageDays = totalDays / opportunities.size();
}
```

**Notes**

1. Avoiding naming variables as `xxxList` or `xxxSet`. Use plurals
2. `oppList` (`opportunities`) will never be null as Trigger.new is never null
3. `averageDays` uses integer arithmetic so if totalDays = 75 and `opportunities.size` is 6, then result is 12, not 12.5.
4. Use `IsClosed` and `IsWon` to avoid binding to the `Stagename` (especially if you have multiple stages that represent closed won for different record types)
5. It's good practice to exit early from loop iteration to avoid nested indented if conditions. Code is easier to read and comprehend. This becomes more apparent as you add more conditions for calculating something within loops. Fewer nested logic paths is better.

Comment: And the rationale behind the `if(condition) { continue;}` bits are that it's (generally) easier for people to reason about code that is indented less (in fewer nested code blocks).

Comment: @DerekF - absolutely; answer edited